# Direct and Inverse efficient mapping of 3D cartesian positions in a 1D array

Tags: mesh, data-structures

I saved a sample of $N$ Cartesian locations $\{x_i, y_j, z_k\}$ inside a one-dimensional array $\mathbf{a} = \{a_l\}_{l = 1}^N$. 
How can I access back (efficiently) the $l$-location of the array $\mathbf{a}$ knowing just the three $i,j,k$ Cartesian indices?

(Fortran/C++ examples would be helpful)

Comment: Are your samples equispaced in x, y and z?

Comment: no, the sample is fully unstructured once it is  saved in the array. Even the grid is not equispaced

Comment: Are you allowed to use some libraries specially written in C++? I suggest VTK and have a look at vtkPoints, which basically gives you very efficient access to unstructured point cloud.